# How to install Ubuntu on Old Computer using a DVD?

Tags: system-installation

I'm new to Linux and am trying to put Ubuntu on a Presario 6000.

I burned Ubuntu onto a DVD and put it in the optical drive, but it keeps saying:

> Non-System disk

or

> Disk error, replace and strike any key when ready

I'm not sure what to do because still trying to learn more about computers and operating systems.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: Using an old computer you might want to think about the different Ubuntu flavours. Xubuntu and Lubuntu are designed to run on old computers. They are lightweight, fast and efficient but less eye candy. You choose!

Comment: You might want to try uNetbootin to make a bootable usb drive. It usually gives a lot less problems in my experience.

Comment: This may be a stab in the dark, but does your computer have a floppy disk drive? If so, make sure there is no disk in the drive.

Answer (score 3):

Presario 6000? It might be a little poky with standard Ubuntu or Kubuntu, but it will be fast enough with Xubuntu or Lubuntu.  Ubuntu (with GNOME) and Kubuntu (KDE) will use more horsepower and memory; Xubuntu and Lubuntu use less memory and might be better choices. Your mileage *will* vary, of course.

Sounds as if the DVD was either
 1) Burned on a DVD-RW disc, and those can't be a System disc, or
 2) Was not burned as a bootable disc, or 
 3) The disc didn't record properly. 
The first is easy to check; eject the disc, and does it say DVD-RW on it? If so, then reuse it for some other purpose.

Some Windows apps don't make bootable discs. You might also have recorded it in non-bootable mode. If the program you use offered to let you add more to the disc later, well, that isn't doing to make a bootable disc. Instead, make sure the disc you burn 'finalizes' the disc. http://cdburnerxp.se/ and http://www.imgburn.com/ are free apps which do burn bootable CD and DVD discs.

Sometimes, a blank disc is bad, or there's dust on it and it doesn't record properly,, and in either of those cases, discard it and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Are you changing your BIOS on boot up? You have to boot computer from optical drive.

http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/ss/bootorderchange.htm

This is usually dependant on your machine. For me to change BIOS, I have to press F2 at boot up screen, which then takes me to boot manager.

Answer (score 1):

The copy you made is not right. Something went wrong making it.
Get a free program called IMGBURN. Use that to burn Ubuntu to a DVD. It will correct everything for you before it starts. Then make sure the Presario is booting to your newly created copy of Ubuntu (look in the bios to be sure). You should have no more problems.